# Unable To Connect to HTTP URL with iOS 9.x device under Codename One

Tags: java, ios9, codenameone

I have a web service in Java running into Glassfish. 
When I try to consume  this WS in iOS it does not works and the method ConnectionRequest.readResponse(InputStream input) receives the input with no information.
If i try to convert it to byte[] it returns NULL.

Actually the service does not arrive in the WS. But it passes to the method ConnectionRequest.readResponse.

When a use the WS with the @GET annotation and consume with GET too it works.

Comment: This seems to have kicked in today (8/30/2016) - ios uses of HTTP get a fast "connection refused" unless the recommended build hint is in place.  I'm not sure if this activation is because apple changed something or codenameone.

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/xcode-migration-take-2.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to recent security exploits Apple blocked some access to insecure URL's which means that http code that worked before might stop working for you on iOS 9. This is generally a good move, you should use https and avoid http as much as possible but that's sometimes impractical especially when working with an internal or debug environment (setting up SSL is a pain).

We considered adding the required build hints by default but it seems that Apple will reject your app if you just include that and don't have a good reason. We could have done it for debug only but then people might have run into it in production.

The solution at the moment is to use the venerable `ios.plistInject` build hint and set it to:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/hiding-url-security-advocacy.html